# How To Limit Number Of Records In CriteriaBuilder Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to limit number of data in CriteriaBuilder so my code is like below.

```
typeQuery.setFirstResult(0);
typeQuery.setMaxResults(10);
typeQuery.getResultList();

but instead of limiting on Database it is fetching whole data and then fetch limit data from session.

so my question is how can i limit rows directly from database?
```

Comment: Impossible, its done just like you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Integer firstItem = 0;
Integer numOfItems = 10;

return entityManager.createQuery(typeQuery).setFirstResult(firstItem).setMaxResults(numOfItems).getResultList();
```

at te moment of execute te query

Answer (score 0):

CriteriaBuilder converts the query to HQL/JPQL, then executes the query.  HQL/JPQL doesn't support `LIMIT` SQL keyword or other similar keywords.  Hence, either using CriteriaBuilder or HQL/JPQL, it is impossible to natively execute a limit query.

Answer (score -1):

You can try limit or row_num with native though. Just another approach.